# Bandwidth term in the thermal noise of a resistor

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

The following example shows how to calculate the spectral density of the noise of a 10k resistor:

[image]

Now if we have the following opamp (at 25C°) where R1 is 10k and the overall gain of the opamp is 5 how can we calculate the RMS noise at the output only due to R1 for 22kHz bandwidth? When we say BW do we mean a low pass filter (with 22kHz cut-off) added at the output of the opamp or at the input signal?

[image]

Is the following correct?

R1_noise_at_output =  Gain × e_n_R1 × sqrt(BW)

R1_noise_at_output = 5 × 12.8nV/sqrt(Hz) × sqrt(22000Hz)

R1_noise_at_output = 9.5μV

Comment: Calculator where you enter BW, temperature and resistor value: https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Thermal-Noise-Calculator.phtml  - multiply by 5 for amplifier with gain of 5 = 9.45 micro volts RMS

Comment: Your class should have shown you the model to use for a resistor with thermal voltage noise -- can you find it in the book or in your notes?

Comment: When we say 22kHz BW, what does that mean in practice? Does that mean adding a low pass filter with 22kHz cut-off at the very output of the opamp?

Comment: If we dont limit the BW ourselves it becomes a bit peculiar.

Comment: It is the bandwidth over which you measure the noise.  If you put a lowpass filter that has a lower cutoff then everything else in the system, then it will be that bandwidth.